# Identify Instagram API Client developer username/handle

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there any way to discover the username/handle of the owner of a registered Instagram API Client? We have the client registered name, client ID, and client secret. We need to change the configuration of the client, which can't be done without identifying the username/handle of the "owner" of the Instagram API Client.

I have a developer who left my business, and he took with him knowledge of which Instagram account created a couple Instagram Client apps we created. We've done a pretty exhaustive search for a couple days trying to find a record of the Instagram username/handle that "owns" the Instagram API Client. But no luck. I'm praying there is some simple way to lookup the developer username/handle given all the other information we have.

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support?

Comment: I've sent a message through the online support form at http://instagram.com/developer. Otherwise, I can't find a way to contact a human other than starting to stalk people on Twitter!